# Referential Integrity Constraint via Trigger deletion

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

I have three tables

1. Patient
2. Dependent
3. Patient_Visit

The primary key of patient table is used in dependent and patient_visit table as a foreign key. I need a trigger on patient table, which checks patient_id in child tables before deletion. 
As for now I have created a trigger but its not working.

```
create or replace trigger deletePatient 
before delete on patient 
for each row 
declare     
       v_count number(5);
       v_count1 number(5); 
begin
     select count(patient_id)   
     into v_count   
     from dependent     
     where patient_id = :old.patient_id;

     if v_count > 0 then 
                 raise_application_error(-20444,'Cannot Delete record');    
     else select count(patient_id)      
          into v_count1         
          from patient_visit        
          where patient_id = :old.patient_id;

         if v_count1 > 0 then 
                   raise_application_error(-20434,'Cannot Delete record');                  
         else  dbms_output.put_line('Deletion Successful');         
         end if;    
     end if;    
end; 
/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @Gergely Bacso it suppose to check patient_id in both child table as i did in above mention code, but if i have record related to patient_id in both the tables then this trigger works fine and raise application error, but if i delete record from one table for example Dependent tabel, then this trigger do not raise application error, instead of this oracle referential integirity constraint voilated and oracle gives error. but as by my code it also raise application in 2nd case. So Not Working

Comment: You should add these details to your question to help people helping you. Try to be as clear as you can. I don't understand this part for example: *"it also raise application in 2nd case"*.

Comment: it should also raise application error becz we still have patient_id being used in 1 table.. so logicallly we can not delete that record from parent table.